# Append object with function in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, android-studio

I have website application and java app. Java users have additional buttons on page, so i need to append one button, to mobile menu and normal sized menu. This is how my java code working

```
...

String javascript = "javascript:"
                    + "$(document).ready(function() {"
                    + "function foobar1() {Android.foobar1();}"
                    + "function foobar2() {Android.foobar2();}"
                    + "function foobar3() {Android.foobar3();}"
                    + "function foobar4() {Android.foobar4();}"
                    + "var foobar1 = document.createElement('div');"
                    + "var foobar2 = document.createElement('div');"
                    + "var foobar3 = document.createElement('div');"
                    + "var foobar4 = document.createElement('div');"
                    + "foobar1.className = 'profilebuttons';"
                    + "foobar2.className = 'profilebuttons';"
                    + "foobar3.className = 'profilebuttons';"
                    + "foobar4.className = 'profilebuttons';"
                    + "foobar1.innerHTML = 'foobar';"
                    + "foobar2.innerHTML = 'foobar';"
                    + "foobar3.innerHTML = 'foobar';"
                    + "foobar4.innerHTML = 'foobar';"
                    + "foobar1.onclick = foobar1;"
                    + "foobar2.onclick = foobar2;"
                    + "foobar3.onclick = foobar3;"
                    + "foobar4.onclick = foobar4;"
                    + "element = document.getElementsByClassName('contentMenu')[0];"
                    + "element.appendChild(foobar1);"
                    + "element.appendChild(foobar2);"
                    + "element.appendChild(foobar3);"
                    + "element.appendChild(foobar4);"
                    + "});";
            view.loadUrl(javascript);
...
```

this is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $products = $(".profilebuttons"),
    $contentMenu = $(".contentMenu"),
    $profileButtons = $('#profileButtons'),
    transferProduct = $(".transferProduct"),
    products = $(".products"),
    productCategorys = $(".productCategorys");
$products.click(function () {
    $profileButtons.find('.profileButtonsCollection').hide();
    $profileButtons.find('.mobileButton').hide();
    $profileButtons.css('display','flex');
    $.each($contentMenu.children(), function (index) {
        if (index === 0) {} else {
            var $cloned = $(this).clone(true,true);
            $(this).removeClass('profilebuttons').appendTo($profileButtons.find('.profileButtonsCollection'));
            $cloned.removeClass('profilebuttons').appendTo($profileButtons.find('#websiteUrls').find('.menu'));
        }
    });
...
```

in jquery example first one working. I dont understand how to clone object with my functions from java code, that they appended in 2 menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by myself. Java side js code:

```
String javascript = "javascript:"
                    + "$(document).ready(function() {"
                    + "var btnscan = $('<div/>', {'class': 'profilebuttons','text': 'foobar1'}),btnads = $('<div/>', {'class': 'profilebuttons','text': 'foobar2'}),btnmap = $('<div/>', {'class': 'profilebuttons','text': 'foobar3'});"
                    + "foobar.bind('click', function(){Android.foobar1();});"
                    + "foobar.bind('click', function(){Android.foobar2();});"
                    + "foobar.bind('click', function(){Android.foobar3();});"
                    + "element = document.getElementsByClassName('contentMenu')[0];"
                    + "foobar1.clone(true,true).appendTo(element);"
                    + "foobar2.clone(true,true).appendTo(element);"
                    + "foobar3.clone(true,true).appendTo(element);"
                    + "});";
            view.loadUrl(javascript);
```

js code:

```
$.each($contentMenu.children(), function (index) {
        if (index === 0) {} else {
            $(this).removeClass('profilebuttons').appendTo($profileButtons.find('.profileButtonsCollection'));
            $(this).clone(true,true).removeClass('profilebuttons').appendTo($profileButtons.find('#websiteUrls').find('.menu'));
        }
    });
```